# Dynamic setting of Domain Axis Min Value Expression

Tags: java, charts, jasper-reports, jfreechart

I have created a timeseries chart and I want the x axis to start at the minimum value of my series, right now the minimum value that is returned from the sql is '2011-06-30' but the x axis seems to start at '2011-05-01'. I tried setting it from the sql by calculating the minumum date and the map it into a java.util.Date field and then setting the field to Domain Axis Min Value Expression but to no luck. 
I'm also using a java Customizerclass to modify the layout for the chart and It seemed to work if I do this in my customizer class:

```
RotatingLabelAxis domainAxis = new RotatingLabelAxis();

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
java.util.Date date = null;
try {
    date = sdf.parse("30.06.2011");  //Would like this to be the first date in plot instead.
} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

domainAxis.setMinimumDate(date);
```

This seemed to make the first value to value to 2011-07-01 wich is correct. The problem is I would like the date "2011-06-30" in the above example to be set from the lowest date in the series instead. Is there a way to do one of the following:
 * Get the minimum date in the series from within the customizerclass.
 * A way to map in the sql querys returned calculated mindate in the right format so I can set it in the field "Domain Axis Min Value Expression" for the graph correctly?
Any help much appreciated.

Comment: JFreeChart's DateAxis.setMinimumDate() expects a java.util.Date argument. You can find the JavaDoc here: http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/DateAxis.html. Why do you think you have to pass java.sql.Date? Regarding the rest of your question I don't see your problem. Please rephrase and explain what "customizerclass" is an why you need it.

Comment: Hi Martin, I have tired using java.util.Date instead and the result seems to be the same. I Also modified my above question and example based on this. I have also tried to clarify the question so hope it's clearer now what I'm after. Just tell me if I should ad any more information to the question or modify something else in it.
Regards
Robert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JFreeChart should set the minimum und maximum on your DomainAxis (`DateAxis`) automatically unless you use [`setAutoRange(false)`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/ValueAxis.html#setAutoRange%28boolean%29) to disabled this feature. If the auto-range doesn't suite your needs, you can use the `setMinumumDate()`/`setMaximumDate()` methods to adapt this range (as you did in your example code).

You did feed the JFreeChart's dataset with values so finding the minimum date should be possible without JFreeChart. However, you could ask the actually used dataset (I assume a [`TimeSeriesCollection`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/time/TimeSeriesCollection.html)) for example like this:

```
XYPlot xyPlot = chart.getXYPlot();
XYDataset dataset = (XYDataset)xyPlot.getDataset();
double lowerBound = dataset.getXValue(0, 0);
double lowerBound = getDomainLowerBound(false);
java.util.Date lowerDate = new java.util.Date((long)lowerBound);
domainAxis.setMinimumDate(lowerDate);
```

Note, that axis have also a margin that is somehting greater than zero by default. Use [domainAxis.setLowerMargin(0.0)](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/axis/ValueAxis.html#setLowerMargin%28double%29) to eliminate this. Analogical for the upper margin.

Comment: Hi Martin, the getDomainLowerBound(false) doesn't seem to exists for the timeseries type of chart. I can get call getLowerBound() for a number of objects due for example: \n
domainAxis.getLowerBound()

Comment: Hi Martin, I found something that worked. getDomainLowerBound(false) didn't seemt to exists as I mentioned above, but it was possible to do this instead. Your answer did set me in the correct direction so if you modify your answer I will mark it as resolved:

 XYPlot xyPlot = chart.getXYPlot();
 XYDataset dataset = (XYDataset)xyPlot.getDataset();

 double lowerBound = dataset.getXValue(0, 0);
 java.util.Date lowerDate = new java.util.Date((long)lowerBound);
          
 domainAxis.setMinimumDate(lowerDate);

Comment: Hi again, I added the correct code to the answer above instead as it looks better. Although I think you need to acknowledge the change for it to work. Thanks for the answer, it really solved my problem.

Comment: Hi Robert! Sorry, I missed mentioning the dataset part in the code. But you got it just as it was meant. I couldn't accept your code changes as I have to less reputation but I edited the code just as you suggested.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I also have that problem with to low reputation. But yeah I guess that should be the complete answer and the question is resolved. Thanks again.